# why does my app complaints about a missing SQL parameter when i already supplied it?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ado.net

I have a stored procedure that takes 18 parameters and one parameter really annoys me. I have passed a BLOB value of type varbinary(max) an image. By default I pass null as the image. however even though I've passed the parameter and when I ran it, it has given me the following error

```
Procedure or function 'USPSVUPDTCourse' expects parameter '@pBookImage', which was not supplied.
```

But as you can see in the first image I have passed the parameter

[First Image-C# code with the throw exception](http://flic.kr/p/kTX1tc)

[Second Image- SQL Store procedure](http://flic.kr/p/kTYF21)

is there away to fix this or do you need further details, my stored procedure is an on going thing, however this is not a logic error and this something else.. : (

Comment: I'd guess that `BookImage`, which is what you are assigning to `@pBookImage` is null

Comment: by default is set to null from the client app also the in DB table column accepts nulls, so why should I give value to it?

Comment: As per the image of your SP, just allow **null** for your **@pBookImage** parameter like this **@pBookImage varbinary(max) = null**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stored procedure check your input param looks like this

```
  @pBookImage varbinary(max) = null
```

this will accept a null parameter in the sp

Comment: @AndrewMC don't forget to mark it as accepted so other question readers know that is question is done.